# Packets lost in Zmq_Push and Zmq_Pull connection

Tags: sockets, zeromq

I am working on a project wherein I have multiple push sockets( created dynamically ) connected to a single pull socket. Here, each push socket sends a unique kind of data to the pull socket and the data size for each messages is less than 1000Bytes and each push socket sends upto 20,000 to 30,0000 such messages. During the peak load the number of push sockets can scale upto 100. So here, there are 100 push sockets connecting to one PULL receiver and each push socket sending 20-30K of messages with size almost 1000Bytes. 
Now, On the PULL side receiver I process these each unique packets and put it into the respective queue, For Ex: If I have 50 PUSH sockets sending in data than on my receiver side there will be 50 queues processing the data. This is required as each queue holds unique set of data which needs to be processed uniquely. Here, I cannot have multiple PULL receivers as the data would then be routed in a round-robin fashion and one set of unique data might go into another one which I don't need.

Here, the problem I am facing is sometimes I see I don't receive all the data sent by the PUSH sockets. I believe there is some data loss that I happening. In order to control this I have setup HWM on both the sides. I tried the below combinations:
1) SNDHWM set to 100 and RCVHWM set to 100
2) SNDHWM set to 10 and RCVHWM set to 10
3) SNDHWM set to 10 and RCVHWM set to 100

Apart from the above configs I have also set the context threads on sender side to be 3 and on the receiver side to be 1. Here, on the sender side there is only one context created from which multiple push sockets are created dynamically as in when the data receives.

But, in all these combinations I find still some packets are missing.

Can someone guide me as in which parameters I need to configure in ZMQ so that I don't end up in packet loss and all the packets I receive on my receiver side. Also, I somehow believe my receiver side processing might be slow due to which this could have happened.

Please pen your thoughts here and guide me if possible.

Comment: Few questions:
1. which transport are you using?
2. zeromq default send and receive watermark is 1,000. Anyway, are you setting the send watermark on the push socket and receive watermark on the receive socket?

Comment: 3. Any change you are sending with ZMQ_DONTWAIT flag?

Comment: 4. If you are closing the push socket immediately after sending you must set ZMQ_LINGER to give it enough time to send all messages, probably fee seconds or milliseconds. Depends on your binding it might be zero.

Comment: I am using the tcp transport and yes, I am setting the water marks on all send sockets and also on the single receive socket...Also, I am not using the ZMQ_DONTWAIT flag hence it's a blocking send call...But, as per the docs of zmq the LINGER is set to -1 by default hence all messages should be sent before socket closes and I am using the zmq 4.3.2 version .... Generally I see this problem occurring when I do usually long runs...Hence, any suggestions from your side as to how can I avoid this packet drop??...Do I need to change the receive buffer settings on my recv socket ??...Just a thought.

Comment: Which binding are you using? Some change default linger

Comment: I am using the libzmq C binding with version 4.3.2 which says the ZeroMQ Core engine is in C++.

Comment: It seems your watermarks settings are very low (100 messages for pick of 30,000), can you try set them to zero (unlimited) for expiremnt to see if you still loose message?

Comment: Ok, I will try setting it to 0 and check. But, I have one more question here, in case I set to 0 then as per ZMQ doc it means "no limit" then on the receiver side if I dont call zmq_recv within the specified period then will not my messages get lost as the sending side has already closed the connection.??...

Comment: With linger disabled on both recv and send watermarks set to zero you are not supposed to loose messages

Comment: Ok..So you mean to keep the LINGER untouched( i.e. Let it be -1 which is the default value applied ) and have the send and recv watermarks to 0. So in this case I would not have any dropped messages correct?..

Comment: Correct, if the pull or push app will crash you will loose everything in the pipe

Comment: Even with the above configuration I still see that some messages are being lost...Do I need to set the Receiver buffer to a higher value in this case?...Any suggestions?..

Comment: Can you try making a minimal code that reproduce the issue?

Comment: Thanks Som for your inputs, actually the above settings worked perfectly. There was a small bug in my application which I found out and after fixing that this issue got resolved..

Comment: Also, I wanted to ask one more thing....As in traditional tcp sockets, each connection can be treated as file-descriptor and can be processed in separate thread( I mean the recv() for this file-descriptor ). On the same lines can we achieve this in the ZMQ, because AFAIK in ZMQ, the ZMQ_RECV(), manages it internally...But here then, we need to process packet by packet instead of getting all the packets parallely processed using the above tcp socket technique...Any thoughts on this as in how this parallel processing for each socket connection can be achieved?....

Comment: You can use inproc Load-Balancer, so one pull socket connects to the wire and forwarding all messages to a push socket. Now for each thread create a new pull socket and connect to the inproc address of the push socket. Also, you can use the scatter-gather socket types, which are thread safe, so you can call zmq_recv from each thread on same socket.

Comment: Hi Som, my issue is a bit different here, on my client side, I have 100's of threads running and each thread is unique with unique data, on my server side I need to process these unique data as they come from the threads, I don't have the liberty to mix data in different threads. In the above suggested point there is a chance of data going into other threads, which causes more burden in processing due to locking mechanisms and other stuffs, hence, I wanted to know is there something like an identifier I can look at on each incoming message and then pass it to the respective inproc to process?.

Comment: For this use case, I would use PUB-SUB, where for each topic only one subscriber is subscribing.

Comment: Hi Som, I actually tried creating 8 zmq pull recv sockets each having a unique port. Now, my clients will be sending data to these 8 sockets in round robin fashion.... But, here I see that after I run this setup for sometime I am getting out of memory crash from ZMQ and it's pointing to decoder_allocators.cpp file of ZMQ....I am not getting why I am getting this error even though I have memory on my system....But, this issue doesnt comes when I have single zmq_recv of Pull socket and all my clients connect to this single Pull socket..... Any thoughts as in why OOM is reported by ZMQ???